# Mouseleave only when mouseenter ends

Tags: javascript, jquery

with the follow code:

```
$('someelement').hover(
    function() {
        console.log('mouseenter begin');
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log('mouseenter ends');
        }, 2000);
    },
    function() {
        console.log('mouseleave begin');
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log('mouseleave ends');
        }, 2000);
    }
)
```

If I enter and leave div at some times (or one time less then 2 seconds) my console get:

```
mouseenter begin
mouseleave begin
mouseenter ends
mouseleave ends
```

I want mouseleave only executed when `mouseenter` ends, but don't know how.

```
mouseenter begin
mouseenter ends
mouseleave begin
mouseleave ends
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a queue...

http://jsfiddle.net/FHPGS/

```
var queue = []

$('someelement').hover(
    function() {
        queue.push('mouseenter begin');
        setTimeout(function() {
            var item = queue.shift();
            if (item)
                console.log(item)
            console.log('mouseenter ends');
        }, 2000);
    },
    function() {
        queue.push('mouseleave begin');
        setTimeout(function() {
            var item = queue.shift();
            if (item)
                console.log(item)
            console.log('mouseleave ends');
        }, 2000);
    }
)
```

Comment: Can you explain what is the essential code, and what is the demonstration code? I don't know how to begin with my code.

Comment: [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10282350/best-attributes-order-in-html-for-dom-queries) is for you. it needs a **master** :)

Comment: @gdoron: I can't improve on Pointy's comments, which is usually the case. :)