# Best attributes order in HTML for DOM queries

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance, dom

Is there an order of attributes which make the DOM queries faster? For example in the beginning\end of the element.

When I traverse the DOM up will it be better to put the attributes in the end and the other way around when I traverse the DOM down?

Comment: Once the HTML is parsed, the attributes become properties of the DOM element node (or of the "attributes" collection, which is almost certainly another object of a similar low-level nature).  Property lookup is very likely to be a hash, so there's probably no relationship between where the attribute appeared in the markup and how it's fetched from the DOM node.

Comment: @Pointy. Can you give me a source of that assumption? thanks.

Comment: @Pointy: why did you write this as a comment, and not as an answer?

Comment: Well, not really; I mean, how would **you** implement a web browser? :-)  Internally it's not very likely that the browser would perform linear searches for node properties, is it?

Comment: @themarcuz well it's sort-of an answer but I can't back it up with anything concrete. I suppose I could look through the Firefox source code :-)

Comment: Oh also note that if we're talking about something like `.querySelectorAll()` then it might even be the case that the DOM node properties are directly accessible via compile-time calculations; that is, they might be like named members of a C++ object, which means that accessing them would be even faster.

Comment: I'm curious to know what you're working on that requires this level of optimization. Or is this just professional curiosity?

Comment: @MikeRobinson. _"professional curiosity"_ :)

Comment: @Pointy. Can you please sum  it all as an answer? I want to upvote  and accept your's comments but I can't... :(

Comment: Well "zeel" has answered with more or less what I was getting at. He needs the rep more than me :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the browser parses the HTML and constructs the DOM. At that point the literal source of the page is not important anymore, thus DOM queries are not effected by the order.

However I personally like to put my id first, then class, then anything else. For readability.